# How to make jquery autocomplete to not cover other content below it?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Currently, I have a text box, with some text under it... I dont want the suggestions to hide my underlying text.. How do I do it ?

I've the sample ready for you to play with : http://jsfiddle.net/xvVKW/18/

edit :

apparently, it seems the question wasn't telling what I wanted, so here goes :

I want the `<div>` below to move a little down, just like how google search with "instant on" does the job... They move the results down to place the suggestions.

edit :

What @thirtydot answered below [ accepted answer ] works fairly well,
but I had done something to change the jquery-ui's classes to do the job temporarily for me. I had removed the `position: absolute;` from class `ui-autocomplete` in jquery's css files. That worked too...

Comment: Are you sure you want to make your autocomplete suggestion list transparent (or in the background)? It would be a mess for the user to read the list's content...

Comment: @thirtydot, @kappa : see how google search with _instant on_ is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/xvVKW/19/)

I added this CSS:

```
#results {
    position: relative
}
```

and changed your JavaScript like this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('#results').css('top', $('.ui-autocomplete').height() + 8);
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $('#results').css('top', 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might need some tweaking but it seems to work.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
});

$("#results").insertAfter(".ui-autocomplete");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Nope... not transparent.. See how google is doing in google instant

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion list is displayed in a DIV that is absolutely positioned. Look at the code and search for the CSS styles.

The solution is to add the DIV to the page's HTML code below the text field and remove any `position:` CSS styles. Since it's empty, it doesn't occupy any space. When content is added, it will grow as needed.

Comment: I didn't understand... Could you please _jsfiddle_ it ? you can use my version posted in the question and alter it and post back a link here ?